# IBM Websphere MQ to Apache Apex Operator Stream?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, apache-apex

I have been searching the INTERNET extensively for a way to use web-sphere MQ in Apache Apex to stream the MQ message through and into a DAG. However, there seems to be no IBM documentation on the matter.

I know it might be similar to ActiveMQ and I might just need to pass in the websphere Jars, however I do not know where to start.

```
 @Override
  public void populateDAG(DAG dag, Configuration conf)
  {
    JMSStringInputOperator amqInput = dag.addOperator("amqIn", 
        new JMSStringInputOperator());

    LineOutputOperator out = dag.addOperator("fileOut", new LineOutputOperator());

    dag.addStream("data", amqInput.output, out.input);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the Test case for the operator and see if it helps to configure?

https://github.com/apache/apex-malhar/blob/master/library/src/test/java/com/datatorrent/lib/io/jms/JMSStringInputOperatorTest.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JMS Input Operators from Apex (malhar) to read from IBM MQ series, but you need the MQ series driver (v6) for JMS which works with both v6 and v8 server. I don't have a link handy for the driver but if you can't find it let me know and I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: IBM MQ v6 has not been supported by IBM since 2012, it may work but you won't get any support out of IBM if there is a problem.